Parallel process rows of a geodataframe to produce multiple geodataframes in Python
I have a function myfunc that takes as input a row of a geodataframe gpd_in and after some processing, returns a new geodataframe with multiple rows. Once the function, myfunc, is applied to each row of the input geodataframe, all the resulting output geodataframes are concatenated to create the final output. Is there a way to apply myfunc in process the rows of the input geodataframe in parallel?
Example:
import geopandas as gpd
def myfunc(row):
    #some processing using different attributes of row and row.geometry 
    #resulting in the creation of list of geometries with their own attributes
    gdf_new = gpd.GeoDataFrame(new_geom_list, columns=['geometry'], geometry='geometry', crs=crs)
    gdf_new['Attr1'] = attr1_list
    gdf_new['Attr2'] = attr2_list
    return gdf_new 

gpd_out = gpd.GeoDataFrame()
crs = gpd_in.crs
for row in gpd_in.itertuples():
    gpd_out = gpd.pd.concat([gpd_out, myfunc(row)], ignore_index = True)
    

Is it possible to run the for loop in parallel?
I tried to use .apply initially but it seems that .apply wont work since myfunc returns a new geodataframe instead of changing a value in the row.
I tried Parallel from joblib as follows:
results = Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(delayed(myfunc)(row) for row in gpd_in.itertuples())

but got the following error:
PicklingError: Could not pickle the task to send it to the workers.
EDIT: Providing a working example as per @Timeless's comment
import numpy as np
import rasterio
from rasterio.transform import from_origin
import geopandas as gpd
import os

work_folder = r"define/your/work/folder"

## CREATING INPUT DATA
# Define the dimensions of the raster
width, height = 100, 100

# Create a raster array with random values between 0 and 1
data = np.random.random((height, width)).astype('float32')

# Define the transform - specifies the bounding box in coordinate system units
transform = from_origin(west=-90, north=45, xsize=0.5, ysize=0.5)

# Define the coordinate reference system (CRS) - using EPSG code for WGS84
crs = 'EPSG:4326'

# Create a new raster file with one band
with rasterio.open(
    os.path.join(work_folder, 'random_raster.tif'),  # file name and path
    'w',                  # w for write mode
    driver='GTiff',       # GeoTIFF format
    height=height,        # number of pixels vertically
    width=width,          # number of pixels horizontally
    count=1,              # number of bands
    dtype=data.dtype,     # data type of the array
    crs=crs,              # coordinate reference system
    transform=transform   # affine transformation matrix
) as dst:
    dst.write(data, 1)  # write data to the first band


x_start, y_start = -90, 45  
x_end, y_end = -50, 10      

# Create a list of linestrings
linestrings = [
    LineString([(x_start+1, y_start-1), (x_end-1, y_end+1)]),
    LineString([(x_start+1, y_start-5), (x_end-1, y_end+5)]),
    LineString([(x_start+2, y_start-7), (x_end-5, y_end+10)]),
    LineString([(x_start+3, y_start-10), (x_end-10, y_end+20)]),
    LineString([(x_start+4, y_start-20), (x_end-30, y_end+30)])
]

# Create a GeoDataFrame from the linestrings
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': linestrings}, crs="EPSG:4326")
gdf["dist1"] = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
gdf["dist2"] = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
gdf.to_file(os.path.join(work_folder,"Lines.shp"))

## PROCESSING
def myfunc(row):
    line = row.geometry
    dist_list = [0, row.dist1, row.dist2, line.length]
    final_coords = []
    with rasterio.open(raster_file) as raster_obj:
        for dist in dist_list:
            Pt = line.interpolate(dist)
            row, col = raster_obj.index(Pt.x,Pt.y)
            window = rasterio.windows.Window(col, row, 1, 1)
            raster_value = raster_obj.read(1, window=window)[0][0]
            final_coords.append((Pt.x, Pt.y, raster_value))
    line_strings = [LineString(final_coords[i:i+2]) for i in range(len(final_coords) - 1)]
    gpd_out = gpd.GeoDataFrame(line_strings, columns=["geometry"], geometry="geometry")
    gpd_out["Dist"] = dist_list[:-1]
    return gpd_out

gpd_in = gpd.read_file(os.path.join(work_folder,"Lines.shp"))   
raster_file = os.path.join(work_folder, 'random_raster.tif')    
gpd_out = gpd.pd.concat([myfunc(row) for row in gpd_in.itertuples()], ignore_index=True).set_crs(gpd_in.crs)


You could do gpd_out = pd.concat([myfunc(row) for row in gpd_in.itertuples()], ignore_index=True).set_crs(gpd_in). Also, can you put in some effort and make an example of your gpd_in and my_func ?

Are you running results = Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(delayed(myfunc)(row) for row in gpd_in.itertuples()) after if __name__ == '__main__': ? If not, this could be the issue. You can also have a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56884020/spacy-with-joblib-library-generates-pickle-picklingerror-could-not-pickle-the it seems adding prefer="threads" to your Parallel call might help.

@Timeless Thank you for your suggestion. Yes, list comprehension is slightly faster than the way I have written my for loop but the core question stays. I need to process the rows of gpd_in parallel to improve performance. I will edit my post and put in a working example shortly.

@antoine using prefer="threads" does work but the overall processing does not speed up even when gpd_in has 600 rows. In my actual code, running the for loop takes roughly 1.71minutes to process 600 rows while Parallel takes 9.3 minutes! Eventualy, the code will be used on geodataframes with 1000-10000 rows.

@MindOverMatter, thanks but your example gives NameError: name 'gpd_in' is not defined. See how to make a Minimal Reproducible Example

@Timeless I have edited the code to create a working example. It also has code to create a simple input dataset. Any suggestions/help is welcome.

Thanks for amending. I think the main problem is that you're opening the raster for each row. Can you try this slightly adjusted approach ?

@Timeless, Thank you for taking the time to modify my code. Your code runs but I am not sure if the rows are actually being processed in parallel.
I ran the code with gpd_in having 5, 50k and 500k features and compared between running a sequential for loop with itertuples ( similar to your first comment) and Parallel (code from your last comment). The times were 0.02s, 63s, 648s for sequential vs 0.09s, 213s, 2365s for Parallel().
Parallel() had 20 concurrent workers for njobs=-1 but still ended up slower. This might have something to do with the GIL, I am not sure at this point.
